# Extremely slow Composer\Autoload\includeFile shown in New Relic for Heroku app

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php, newrelic

In New Relic, I can see a transaction trace for a PHP 5.6 application that's hosted on Heroku. The transaction took 21,600ms to execute and 87% of that was `Composer\Autoload\includeFile`. From my understanding, `Composer\Autoload\includeFile` simply consists of `include $file;`, so I'm at a loss.

This problem is not occurring frequently, and most transactions of this type seem fine.

What could be taking so long?

Comment: I'm facing the same recently. Even with the --optimize-autoloader flag, my app is having slow responses every 5 seconds.. I debugged it using xdebug and found out that the problem is at the composer autoload as well. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score -2):

I get the same result with Composer. Composer manages libraries really quite easy, but the loading speed is slow by default. You should use "--optimize-autoloader" flag to deploy your code in production environment. Otherwise, you will lost 20%-25% performance.

Comment: if you can please explain how you do that?

Comment: @Leirith I have the same issue, though i did run --optimize-autoloader (or php artisan optimize).  Still search for causes